# White box appearing next to button on hover - css issue?

Tags: html, css

I can't for the life of me figure out what is causing this little white box when hovering over a button. I've recreated the code on codepen and it isn't there.

The html for the section is:

```
<div class="custom">
    <h3><span style="color: #ffffff; margin-top: 50px;"><br>
    Thinking of a new website?</span></h3>
    <p style="text-align: left;"><span style="color: #ffffff;">Get started with this free guide</span></p>
    <h4 style="text-align: left; margin-top: 20px;"><span style="color: #ffffff;">8 Steps To A High Impact Website Redesign</span><br>
    <span style="color: #ffffff;"><small>How To Finally Get Your Website Sorted (And Actually Getting Results)</small></span></h4>
    <p style="text-align: left;"><span style="color: #ffffff;"><a class="manual-optin-trigger" data-optin-slug="rnrqwxq9x7zlekfs" href="#" style="color: #ffffff;"><span class="btn">Send me the guide</span></a></span></p>
</div>
```

There are a couple of extensive stylesheets which apply to the page, so I'm not sure whether it would be easier to view the page here.

The button in question is the one about half way down under the heading 'Thinking of a new website?'. If you hover over the button that says 'Send me the guide' you will see it turns yellow and a white box appears to the right of it....I'm baffled???

Can anyone provide any ideas as to what might be causing it?

Thank you in advance.
D

Comment: remove this `background-color` - `#grid14 a:hover, #grid15 a:hover {
    background-color: #fff!important;`

Comment: @MichaelCoker Thank you - I thought i'd unchecked that in dev tools when I was looking, obviously not. Wood and trees and all that :)